# Mute/Unmute Microsoft Teams Microphone Using Mouse Button when Teams is Not Focused

Tags: shortcut, microphone

I would like to mute and unmute Microsoft Teams, using a spare mouse button, when the application is not focussed.  I am using a Microsoft Sculpt mouse and have a couple spare buttons, particularly the navigate back button, which I would like to reassign to the mute function.

The reason I want to do this is because I am typically having a conversation while working in another application and I want to avoid the delay and context switching of having to focus the Teams Application before either clicking on the mute button or using the command+shift+m keyboard shortcut.

It's inconvenient enough that I have considered using something like Touch Portal on my phone to create an easy hot button but that application isn't signed.

Microsoft does not provide Mac drivers for the Sculpt Ergonomic Mouse or Sculpt Ergonomic desktop.

Comment: MS provides an app for most of its mice that allows you to assign the buttons on the mouse to various actions. Does this not work, and what have you tried with that software. Please *EDIT* ( https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/410517/edit ) your question with that info.

Comment: There are many mouse control apps… the trouble is they will all send the control to the front-most app. This is going to require some solution that will send to an app backgrounded - which I've no clue how to approach :\

Answer (score 0):

here is an API call using graph, that does something like you are asking.

https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/participant?view=graph-rest-1.0&viewFallbackFrom=graph-rest-v1.0#properties

They also have an API call to mute
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/participant-mute?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

However I don't think you are going to get the feature you want, because when you are using teams, you are not allowed to unmute someone else, and the API has no idea the person you would be trying to unmute, is you.

One thing that should be pretty easy, is to mute/unmute the mic at the operating system level. This would work, however your co-workers would not know you are muted.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I got this working with Touch Portal on Windows. I suspect you are on a Mac due to this being Apple exchange, but I used built in Touch Portal features, so hopefully it works for you as well. This is an action to mute at windows level. However when I do this, it also toggles the mute icon in Teams. So on windows anyway, Teams in integrated with the system level mute. Give it a shot :)

[image: setup for mute]

Comment: Two things about this. One is the button status is unimportant. You can remove that if you are swamping images. Secondly, if you mute in teams, the touch portal will not unmute you (I guess it's a security feature), however if you mute with touch portal, you can then unmute with it.